# Ошибка KeyError при попытке записи в csv файл результата парсинга

Tags: python, csv, requests, beautiful-soup

При завершении парсинга и попытке записать в csv файл результат возникает ошибка ключа 'category', при этом в функцию передается корректный  аргумент. Помогите плиз!

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv


def get_html(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    return response.text


def refined(string):
    rating = string.split(' ')[0]
    return rating.replace(',', '')


def write_csv(data):
    with open('plugins.csv', 'a') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file)
        print(data)
        print(type(data))
        writer.writerow((data['category'],
                         data['name'],
                         data['url]'],
                         data['rating']))


def get_data(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    sections = soup.find_all('section')
    data = {}
    n = 0
    for section in sections:
        section_header = section.find('header').find('h2').text
        plugins = section.find_all('article')
        for plugin in plugins:
            name = plugin.find('h2').text
            url = plugin.find('h2').find('a').get('href')
            rating = plugin.find('span', class_='rating-count').find('a').text
            rating = refined(rating)
            data[n] = {'category': section_header,
                       'name': name,
                       'url': url,
                       'rating': rating}
            n += 1
    return data


def main():
    url = 'https://wordpress.org/plugins'
    data = get_data(get_html(url))
    write_csv(data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Вот что выдает консоль:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/dgs/parser/2.py", line 53, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/dgs/parser/2.py", line 49, in main
    write_csv(data)
  File "C:/Users/dgs/parser/2.py", line 19, in write_csv
    writer.writerow((data['category'],
KeyError: 'category'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: У вас data[n] равняется тому, что вам надо, а не data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас data[n] равняется тому, что вам надо, а не data